# Why am I unable to remove the Ubuntu One icon?

Tags: 11.04, unity, ubuntu-one, uninstall

I have removed the Ubuntu One icon from the Unity launcher and it keeps returning. I right click the icon and uncheck the 'Keep in Launcher' option.

I do not use this service and I want to remove it permantly from my launcher.

Comment: You have to provide more information. Which version of Ubuntu are you using, for instance? Is the u1 client being run, is that the reason it comes back, or do you need to uncheck "Keep in launcher" every time?

Comment: I am using 11.04 and I remove the button from the launcher, but after I shutdown the machine and then boot again later the icon has returned. I must uncheck the "Keep in launcher" each time to remove it.

Comment: You should file a bug, then. You do that on Launchpad.net

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem:

run this in console:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk.desktop
```